# Is there a good resource for information on infinite double series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation, online-resources

I’m trying to understand them more and neither Wikipedia or Wolfram MathWorld is helping too much. For instance, what tests for convergence of infinite double series are valid, rules for them, important double series, etc.

Comment: [This is one of the references in MathWorld's article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8b7f/068aebfd51fa50966ce60086dc5a02ce9aee.pdf)

Comment: The book “A Course in Multivariable Calculus and Analysis” by Ghorpade and Limaye has so much on double series

Comment: One place is [**An introduction to the theory of infinite series**](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoth00bromuoft) by Bromwich (1908; see Chapter on pp. 72-94).